# How can I add a class to each menu item in WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

On My html code there was a class in Menu element, the class was in every li a item. class name is="page-scroll", So it look like `<li><a class="page-scroll" href="#screenshots">Screenshots</a></li>`

this class is used in jquery file for Smooth Scroll. Now in wordpress i register a menu and now i want to add this class "page-scroll" in every menu li a element so that the smooth scroll work.

everything work perfectly in html now it need to be perfect in wordpress.

jQuery for Smooth Scroll-

```
$('.page-scroll').on('click', function (event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to look into modifying your PHP templates. This isn't a jQuery question. Even if you added those classes with jQuery, smoothScroll probably won't see them unless you re-initialize the plugin afterward.

Answer (score 2):

In the menu page in wordpress admin, goto Screen Options & enable CSS Classes.

Now you can add css classes to each menu items directly from the admin without a need to edit the code.

Please check https://en.support.wordpress.com/advanced-menu-settings/

Comment: it did not work, i tried it. it added the class in li i need in every li > a  element

Comment: @Shovon, I think you can easily achieve this using jQuery. Try using the selector like $('.page-scroll a') or $('.page-scroll > a') based on your needs instead of $('.page-scroll')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put a class in your **ul** tag, and use the selector as $('.page-scroll a'). To insert a class in the **ul** you can use [wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) and pass the class name in the parameters. Something like this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'YOUR MENU',
                'menu_class'        => 'page-scroll'
            ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-menu-class/.
Hope it will do for you too.